# count characters in batch with in loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, count

I try to get (echo) the files in a directory (with subdirectorys) where the filename is longer than 16 characters. therefore I play around with this script:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%f in (*) do (
  set /p val=<%%f
  REM echo "fullname: %%f"
  REM echo "path: %%~pf"
  REM echo "name: %%~nxf"
  REM set test=%%~nxf
  REM echo %test%
  if "%%~nxf:~16%" == "" echo "Less than 16 characters."
  if not "%%~nxf:~16%" == "" echo "Bigger than 16 characters."
)

pause
GOTO :EOF
```

But I get on every file "Bigger than 16 characters."! I also try to set the var `%test%` to `%%~nxf` (the filename) but get only "Echo is off" because the var `%test%` is not set?

How to set the var `%test%` with the filename and how to get "Less than 16 characters." if the filename has only 6 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `delayedexpansion` you enabled earlier, also you cannot use substitution or positioning on a metavariable, you need to assign it to a variable first:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*) do (
  set "line=%%~nxi"
  if "!line:~16!"=="" (
    echo !line! is less than 16 characters.
  ) else echo !line! is 16 or more characters.
)
```

see the help `cmd` by running:

```
set /?
```

Scroll down to `Delayed environment` section.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is `I try to get (echo) the files in a directory (with subdirectories) where the filename is longer than 16 characters.`.

`dir /s /b ????????????????*.*` won't work, because the wildcard `?` means `zero or one character`.

Gladly `where` handles wildcards differently: `?` is `exactly one character` and `*` is `any number of characters (including zero)`.

So the following line should do exactly what you want: display all files whose name *plus extension* (according to your code attempt `%~nxf`) is 16 characters or more:

```
 where /r . ????????????????*
```

To get all files whose name *without* extension is 16 chars or more:

```
where /r . ????????????????*.*
```

(might get false positives, as `file.with.several.extensions.txt` or `file-without-extension` - where `false` depends on your expectations)